# Personalization error - "Make sure that there is not a space or typo within the personalization string"

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, validation, email-validation

Here's my email's code:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <body> Your unique link is: <a href="%%UniqueLink%%">%%UniqueLink%%</a></body>
   </head>
</html>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="600" ID="Table5" Border=0>
   <tr>
      <td><font face="verdana" size="1" color="#444444">This email was sent by: <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br></font></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a>
```

When I go to "preview/test", here's what I see:

[image]

There are no spaces in my personalization string.  Any ideas what might be causing this?  The data extension tied to the preview/test has UniqueLink as a field.  Also, the text version is okay in terms of no spaces with UniqueLink.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend ***not*** using naked personalization strings.  Always check them with [**AttributeValue()**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue).

You'll get errors like this if your send context doesn't contain the personalization/substitution string referenced.

```ampscript
%%[ 

var @uniqueLink
set @uniqueLink = AttributeValue("UniqueLink")

if empty(@uniqueLink) then
  raiseError("missing unique link", 1)
endif

]%%
<html>
   <head>
   <body> Your unique link is: <a href="%%=redirectto(@uniqueLink)=%%">%%=v(@uniqueLink)=%%</a></body>
   </head>
</html>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="600" ID="Table5" Border=0>
   <tr>
      <td><font face="verdana" size="1" color="#444444">This email was sent by: <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br></font></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a>
```

Comment: Adam, always with the super knowledgeable answers!  Appreciate it.

Comment: Sweet. Would you mind checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.